# How to convert sql date to Joda Datetime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

I'm working with date sql and `getDay()` returns the day of the week represented by this date. The returned value (`0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, 4 = Thursday, 5 = Friday, 6 = Saturday`)

```
//type of dateStart and dateEnd is  java.sql.Date
//type of DateTime is joda.time.DateTime
public static Date[][] getListPeriod(Date dateStart , Date dateEnd){
DateTime start = new DateTime(dateStart.getYear()+1900,dateStart.getMonth()+1,dateStart.getDay(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Example : value of the dateStart : 2015-07-01 
and `dateStart.getDay()` return 2015-07-03  (3 = Wednesday)

I want `dateStart.getDay()`  get this value  1

Comment: If you are only interested in a calendar date then you should better consider the type `LocalDate` not `DateTime`. This way you get a much better mapping from SQL-DATE to a plain date (without any time or zone part).

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`new DateTime(dateStart.getTime())`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#DateTime(long)) ?

To get the day (of the month) from a `java.sql.Date`, you have to use [`getDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDate--). This method is inherited from `java.util.Date` and deprecated. The correct way to get parts from a date is to use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).